# nginx: combine Expires and Cache-Control: immutable headers

Tags: nginx

nginx `expires` directive sets 2 headers, `Expires` and `Cache-Control`:

Config:

```
expires 1d;
```

Headers:

```
Expires: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 12:51:31 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
```

I would like to keep `Expires` header but also set `Cache-Control` to `public, max-age=86400, immutable`. But that produces double `Cache-Control` headers:

Config:

```
expires 1d;
add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400, immutable"
```

Headers:

```
Expires: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 12:57:53 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400, immutable
```

I can not just use `add_header Expires ...`, because it requires exact time in future, not just number of seconds.

I tried using `more_set_headers` from [ngx_headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module, but `Cache-Control` header set by `expires` directive is still there.

Is there any way to combine correct `Expires` header with `Cache-Control` set to `immutable`?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/772507/set-expires-and-cache-control-headers-on-nginx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Duplication of the `Cache-Control` headers isn't a violation of any W3C standard. According to [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

Moreover, nginx is aware about it, trying to set a header which shouldn't contain more than one value with the `add_header` nginx directive will lead to overwrite that header value rather then adding the second one. So you can safely stay with the

```
expires 1d;
add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
```

configuration.

Answer (score 5):

The Cache-Control: header can appear more than once, provided that the two headers do not try to use the same directives. If they do, that directive is ignored. (RFC 7234 § 4.2.1)

Thus you can let nginx send its header with the `max-age` directive, and send your own with only the other directives.

The result would be:

```
Expires: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 12:57:53 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Cache-Control: public, immutable
```

(But if `max-age=86400` appeared in both headers it would be ignored.)

It's normal and expected that certain header fields may appear more than once. RFC 7230 § 3.2.1 specifies that recipients may combine them into a single header, but this is not required.

Comment: Thanks! Can't accept both answers, though.